# Show bound on difference involving complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm an undergraduate student taking a graduate level complex analysis seminar, so I hope this question is okay:

During a discussion on basic properties of the $\zeta$ function, the professor asserted:

> For a complex number $s$ with strictly positive real part (call it $a$), the following holds:
> $$|1/n^s-\int_n^{n+1}1/x^s dx|\leq K_a/n^{a+1}$$

for some $K_a$. He did not prove this (and suggested that we try it as an exercise), but I've been unable to prove it.

I've done the following "obvious" thing of taking the antiderivative, assuming that $s\neq 1$.
$|1/n^s-\int_n^{n+1}1/x^s dx|=|1/n^s-(1/(1-s))((n+1)^{1-s}-n^{1-s})|$ but nothing is really jumping out in the way of next steps.

I hope this was a good first question! Please let me know if I can improve in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proof is introduced in Stein& Shakarchi's Complex Analysis book, but there is a minor error. I give more accurate version.

We have \begin{align*}
\left|\frac{1}{n^s}-\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{dx}{x^s}\right| &= \left|\int_n^{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{n^s}-\frac{1}{x^s}\right)dx\right|\\
&\le \sup_{x\in[n, n+1]}\left|\frac{1}{n^s}-\frac{1}{x^s}\right|\\
&= \sup_{x\in[n, n+1]}\left|\int_n^x\frac{s}{y^{s+1}}dy\right|\\
&\le \sup_{x\in[n, n+1]}(x-n)\sup_{y\in[n, x]}\frac{|s|}{|y^{s+1}|}\\
&\le\sup_{y\in[n, n+1]}\frac{|s|}{y^{\Re s+1}}\\
&\le \frac{|s|}{n^{a+1}}
\end{align*} where the integral in third line is contour integral taken in straight-line path from $n$ to $x$(or just integral of real variable complex valued function), and the next line follows in spirit of ML-inequality. The constant $K_a$ may not be uniform in $s$, but is uniform in every compact set $\{s:|s|\le M, \Re s\ge a\}$. This suffices to prove holomorphicity of the sum function you will see.

Comment: So basically this proof is not taking antiderivative, but rather differentiating again.